# The ConTeXt standalone problem

Tags: installing, context, context-mkiv

Today I installed the `ConTeXt standalone` by following the `Windows Installation: ConTeXt Suite with SciTe`. After that, I wrote a test file:

```
\starttext
hello, world!
\stoptext
```

But failed, the output info is as follows:

```
d:\latex>context 00contexttest.tex
context 00contexttest.tex

mtxrun          | forcing cache reload
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file 'C:/Users/tim/texmf/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file 'D:/context/tex/texmf-mswin/bin//texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file 'D:/context/tex/texmf-mswin/bin//share/texmf-local/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file 'D:/context/tex/texmf-mswin/bin//share/texmf-dist/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file 'D:/context/tex/texmf-mswin/bin//texmf-local/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file 'D:/context/tex/texmf-mswin/bin//texmf-dist/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file 'D:/context/tex/texmf-mswin//texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file 'D:/context/tex/texmf-mswin//share/texmf-local/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file 'D:/context/tex/texmf-mswin//share/texmf-dist/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file 'D:/context/tex/texmf-mswin//texmf-local/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file 'D:/context/tex/texmf-mswin//texmf-dist/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file 'D:/context/tex//../texmf-local/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file 'D:/context/tex//texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file 'D:/context/tex//share/texmf-local/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file 'D:/context/tex//share/texmf-dist/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file 'D:/context/tex//texmf-local/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file 'D:/context/tex//texmf-dist/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving |
resolvers       | resolving | warning: no lua configuration files found
resolvers       | resolving | no texmf paths are defined (using TEXMF)
resolvers       | resolving |
mtxrun          | the resolver databases are not present or outdated
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-context.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-contexts.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembered file 'mtx-context.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-t-context.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-t-contexts.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembered file 'mtx-t-context.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'context.lua'
mtxrun          | unknown script 'context.lua' or 'mtx-context.lua'
d:\latex>
```

Now, I have gotten no idea to solve this problem. I have tried run `setuptex` in ../context/tex/, but in vain.

Comment: Did you call `setuptex.bat` before running `context`? Try running `mtxrun -- generate`

Comment: @Aditya yeah, although I have called `setuptex.bat`, I still get the same message and `mtxrun --generate` is also  abnormal.

Comment: I don't use Windows so it is hard for me to suggest what could be happening. If you don't get any answer here, post of the context mailing list. Hans Hagen, the main developer of ConTeXt, uses Windows + Scite, so you are sure to get an answer there.

Comment: @Aditya Thanks. The next step, will be learing to use the mailing lists that I haven't used that before. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try running `first-setup` again.

Hans sent an e-mail to the list yesterday saying "[don't update from the garden](http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2013/072272.html), the configuration seems broken."

I didn't try the broken beta, so I don't know if you and he are talking about the same problem, but it seems like. Hans uploaded a new beta this morning, which I fetched with `first-setup` and which compiles fine for me.

Like Aditya said, your question was probably better-suited to the mailing list — and you would be very welcome there, of course. Sign up for the [ConTeXt mailing list](http://www.ntg.nl/mailman/listinfo/ntg-context) at NTG.nl.

Comment: This morning, I reinstalled ConTeXt standalone and everything was OK :-)

Comment: In that case, I'm flagging this question for deletion as 'too localized'. It was a perfectly good question, don't worry; but the question + my answer will be completely outdated in a week's time, so keeping it around won't help future users.

Comment: Also: glad to hear your installation works now. Happy ConTeXting!

Comment: ConTeXt is supercool :-) I also think we should close this question.